# Визначати напрям руху за зірками чи по зірках?

Tags: прийменники

Є таке речення: "У давнину мореходці визначали своє місце перебування і напрям руху *по* сузір'ях". Викликає сумнів правильність вживання прийменника *по*. Здається, правильніше було би сказати "*за сузір'ями*". За [мовною консультацією](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-po-krok-tretij/) проф.Пономарева,

> замість прийменника ПО вживаємо прийменник ЗА, якщо йдеться про якийсь
> принцип, критерій, ознаку.

Чи можна вважати рух орієнтовно небесних тіл критерієм? Чи в цьому випадки припустиме вживання прийменника *по*?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно буде сказати: "напрям руху за зірками". Дивимось статтю "[Типові помилки у вживанні прийменників](http://posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/u_m/3.htm)":

> Прийменник "по" функціонує в українській та російській мовах, однак у
>   російській мові це один з найуніверсальніших прийменників і
>   конструкції з ним виражають велику кількість найрізноманітніших
>   відношень.
>
> В українській мові прийменник "по" вживають з іменниками, займенниками,
>   числівниками; конструкції з ним виражають такі відношення:
>
> а) часові: по обіді, маю відпустку по 15 березня, приїду по святах
>   (іноді можна замінити іменником у родовому відмінку з прийменником
>   після – після свят);
>
> б) об’єктні: погладив по голівці, по коліна у воді;
>
> в) мети: пішов по воду, пішла по гриби (і за грибами), поїхав по рибу;
>
> г) кількісні відношення: по 25 осіб у групі; працює по 10 годин на
>   добу;
>
> д) найчастіше вживаємо цей прийменник на позначення просторових
>   відношень: по садочку ходжу, по діброві вітер віє.

Також варто процитувати ось цю [статтю](https://www.ar25.org/article/vzhyvannya-pryymennyka-po.html):

> Прийменник "по" властивий українській мові, коли йдеться про місце дії
>   (“По діброві вітер виє, гуляє по полю...” Т. Шевченко), мету дії
>   (пішли у ліс по грибочки), час (по обіді, по канікулах), міру,
>   кількість чогось (по цукерці, по сотні), а також сферу діяльності (по
>   господарству, по службі).
>
> Функціонування прийменника "по" у таких випадках є нормативним. Проте
>   надужиття цим прийменником призводить до небажаних повторень певних
>   висловів, що сьогодні трапляється доволі часто.

Як бачимо якщо, ми скажемо "рух по зорях", то ми матимемо на увазі місце дії, тобто, що ми справді ходимо по зорях. Тому варто замінити прийменник "по" на "за", однак слід пам'ятати, що в залежності від контексту "по" також можна замінити прийменниками "з", "на", "через" тощо (див. [Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE/)).