# "Та, що біжить по хвилях"

Tags: дієприкметники

Як буде українською "Та, що біжить по хвилях"? Це назва твору, як ви розумієте. "Та, что біжить по хвилях" - недобре ... Да ще прийменник "по"

Питання не нове, відповіді хорошей я не бачив.

@bytebuster

> Також варто пояснити, чим вам не подобається назва, що виведена у
> заголовку допису

Занадто довго для назви і нелюбимий українською прийменник "по"

Comment: Уточніть, що означає «недобре», і що таке «Дп». Також варто пояснити, чим вам не подобається назва, що виведена у заголовку допису. Окрім того, у нас заохочуються запитання, які демонструють власні спроби автора знайти відповідь на запитання. «відповідей хороших не бачив» не виглядає достатнім аргументом.

Comment: @bytebuster Дл - помилка, дякую. А недобре - погано. А що незрозуміло?

Comment: @bytebuster *Окрім того, у нас заохочуються запитання, які демонструють власні спроби автора знайти відповідь на запитання. «відповідей хороших не бачив» не виглядає достатнім аргументом* - "бежить волнами/хвилями" - наприклад.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Як на мене, то *Та, що біжить по хвилях* це чудова назва. Але можна ще

- *Бігунка по хвилях.*

Прийменник *по* цілком прийнятний в українській мові. Ось тут більше про це [Визначати напрям руху за зірками чи по зірках?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85/4700#4700)

Comment: О! Дякую. "Бігунка" - це добре. Що до прийменика - не зовсім ще зрозуміло, але це окреме питання

Comment: Бігунка - це ще деколи синонім діареї.